# Having problem while converting string to numbers

Tags: python, string, integer

I am having problem while converting the string to integer can any body help me in doing so or any alternative method?

```
x=int("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6")

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a list of integers, do the following:

```
s = "4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"
x = list(map(int, s.split()))
# [4, 5, 29, 54, 4, 0, -214, 542, -64, 1, -3, 6, -6]

print(max(x), min(x))
```

Comment: hello, if I want to get max an min numbers and want to print it in the form "542 -241", what may be the solution.

Comment: Added that line.

Answer (score 0):

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6'

The [ValueError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) exception clearly says it can't convert your str to an int with base 10.

[int()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) says:

> If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string,
>   bytes, or bytearray instance representing an integer literal in radix
>   base.

`x = int("2")` would have worked. However, your string contains a sequence of `int`. You can't convert your `str` to an `int` using `int` constructor.

You need to use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) or [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to get a list of int and then operate on them.

Using `list comprehension`:

```
s = "4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"
li = [int(i) for i in s.split()]
print(li)
```

Using `map`:

```
s = "4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"
print(list(map(int, s.split())))
```

Outputs:

```
[4, 5, 29, 54, 4, 0, -214, 542, -64, 1, -3, 6, -6]
```

**EDITED:**

```
s = "4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"
li = [int(i) for i in s.split()]
print(max(li), min(li))
```

OUTPUTS:

```
542 -214
```

Comment: hello, if I want to get max an min numbers and want to print it in the form "542 -241", what may be the solution.

Comment: I have up voted but i have less reputations so stack overflow dont accept

Answer (score 0):

Number "4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6" does not exist. Divide it (suggest in other comments).
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html?highlight=int#int